# Как изменить имя ключа в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Желательно не удаляя объект и без клонирования

```js
let obj = {0.25: 'Name'};

console.log(obj[0.25]);

// найти в объекте ключ 0.25 и заменить его на 0.26
console.log(obj[0.26]);
```

Comment: никак. Ключи можно только удалить и добавить

Comment: Вообще идея делать ключи вещественными числами попахивает безумием.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, почему? Они приведутсЯ в строку и все ок

Comment: @Grundy а потом автор захочет их складывать и привет 0.1+0.2

Comment: @AlexeyTen, или не захочет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {0.25: 'Name'};

console.log(obj[0.25]);

obj[0.26] = obj[0.25];
delete obj[0.25];

console.log(obj[0.26]);
```